# Совмещение js и php

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin, dom

Здраствуйте, у меня есть одна проблема. Я не могу понять как допустим по нажатию кнопки отправить данные в БД? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        <?php
            echo "1"; 
        ?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: послать запрос на `API` ? Воспользоваться `fetch`'ом, сформировать данные и отправить их и на бэке получить?!?!?!?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        fetch('ссылка на пхп обработчик',
              method:'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify({
                  name: 'dean',
                  login: 'dean',
              }))
        .then((response)=>{
           console.log(response) // Тут ответ от сервера
        
         })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error) // Будет вызвано если от сервера вернется ошибка
        })
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Так ты не отправишь. Нужно понять взаимосвязь.

JS это код на стороне клиента. php отрабатывает на сервере. Связь с базой осуществляется с помощью php.

То есть скрипт js должен отправит заброс на сервер. На сервере выполниться php скрипт в котором и будет обращение к базе данных.

Отправить данные в php скрит из js можно следующими способами или используя form через get post запрос. Или используя ajax.

Далее Скрипт php получает данные, и вызывает функцию обращения к базе данных.Теоретически это выглядит так.

Чтоб понять глубже нужно изучить.

1. Отпарка данных на сервер js
2. Работа с MySQL в PHP
   и тогда все встанет на свои места.